# Solr query which return only those docs whose all tokens are from given list

Tags: solr

I have `Solr` docs in which tags field is indexed :

```
Doc1 -> tags:T1 T2  
Doc2 -> tags:T1 T3  
Doc3 -> tags:T1 T4
Doc4 -> tags:T1 T2 T3
```

**Query 1:** get all docs with `tags:T1 AND tags:T3` then it works and will
          give Doc2 and Doc4

**Query 2:**  get all docs whose tags must be one of these [T1, T2, T3]
           Expected is :  Doc1, Doc2, Doc4
           How to model this in `Solr` Query?

Answer (score 1):

check the link for more

http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

```
q=tags:(T1 OR T2 OR T3)

 tags:(T1 AND T2 AND T3)

 tags:(T1 AND T2 OR T3)
```

Comment: none of these will give expected result...i want all docs whose tags must be subset of  [T1, T2, T3, T5, T6, T7, T8]..here only Doc1, Doc2, Doc4 qualifies..please give second thought

Comment: How did you build the query? can you share it? whats the default search field?

Comment: hi abhijit, i also posted this on solr forum so if you read this discussion then will understand my problem  : http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-query-which-return-only-those-docs-whose-all-tokens-are-from-given-list-td4204831.html

Comment: any solution to this please help

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your problem correctly Using field query (fq)is the right solution in this case

`fq = tags:("T1", "T2","T3","T5", "T6", "T7", "T8")`